# Android:Button slides like a slider?

Tags: android, button, seekbar

I have a button and what i wanna do  is to make it slide like a thumb in the seekbar. Is there any way to achieve this ?
Thanks FIRST!

Answer (score 0):

Please check in the ApiDemos project under Views -> Animation -> Interpolators. Is that what you would like to achieve? 
If so you can use the code as an example. Instead of the TextView you may also use a button.

How to get the ApiDemos Project: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/get.html

Comment: @ZhaoRocky:: hi i also need to implement like this can u explain me how to do it?